# Faulty input gets validated as faulty, but behaves as if it's correct

Tags: java, swing, validation, components

I have a few components which I want to check whether or not they are filled in.
My code iterates over every component added to a list, casts it to the correct type, invokes the `getText` method and checks whether or not it's empty. In case it's empty, a boolean is set to false and returned. Depending on the boolean, "Yay" (success) or "Nay" (failed) is being shown. As additional testing I have also printed `component.toString()` each time it failed.

The problem right now is this: every `component.toString()` method is called in a situation where every component has text. Regardless of my input, the boolean remains success (even when some fields have no text in them).

During debugging I've found that none of my components have a field 'Text' or 'getText' or similar in my debugging window (Eclipse), which might be an indication of the problem.

I can't find the problem, can someone point me to it?

```
boolean success = checkInput();
if (success) {
    System.out.println("Yay");
} else {
    System.out.println("Nay");
}
```

checkInput method

```
private boolean checkInput() {


    boolean success = true;
    List<Component> components = new ArrayList<Component>();
    components.add(txtLeertrajectCode);
    components.add(txtLeertrajectTitel);
    components.add(txtOmschrijving);
    components.add(txtDoelgroep);


    for (Component comp : components) {
            if (comp instanceof JTextField) {
                String curr = ((JTextField) comp).getText().trim();
                if ("".equals(curr)) {
                    System.out.println(comp.toString());
                    comp.setForeground(Color.RED);
                    success = false;
                } else {
                    comp.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
            } else if (comp instanceof JTextArea) {
                String curr = ((JTextArea) comp).getText();
                if ("".equals(curr)) {
                    System.out.println(comp.toString());
                    comp.setForeground(Color.RED);
                    success = false;
                } else {
                    comp.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
            }

        }

        return success;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
javax.swing.JTextField[...] 
javax.swing.JTextField[...]
javax.swing.JTextArea[...] 
javax.swing.JTextField[...] 
Yay
```

**EDIT:**

Problem solved, appearantly I had my textfields twice, but under a similar name in the file. Obviously the checking was done on the textfields not in use.
Silly problem.

Comment: How would we have been able to guess at the problem given the information originally posted? Voting to close as too localized. This question will not likely help anyone in the future.

Comment: this is job for DocumentListener / DocumentFilter with InputMask

Comment: @mKorbel: is of course right on the money and has looked at the bigger picture. Your complete approach can be greatly improved by following his suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you should change this:

```
} else {
    System.out.println("Yay");
}
```

to

```
} else {
    System.out.println("Nay");
}
```

Comment: You're right, that was a typo. Problem remains though, my correct input is validated as wrong.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Please at least up-vote the answer for catching your typo.

Answer (score 0):

I think everything all right. You have JTextFiled but it is not containing text (it is simply empty)

**UPDATE**

```
I write simple example
results = new JTextArea();
        System.out.println("First :" + results.getText());
        results.setText("Test");
        System.out.println("Second :" + results.getText());
```

and outpur look like this:

```
First :
Second :Test
```

so may be you insert values into textfields after check???

Comment: I type some random characters each time I test this, all 3 textfields and 1 textarea contain text.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Could you print `curr` value along with `comp.toString()`?

Comment: When printing `curr` I receive blank lines, definitely indicating `curr` is an empty value. When I place `System.out.println(txtLeertrajectCode.getText());` in front of the loop, I get another empty value. For some reason all textfields are considered empty.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel look update

Comment: My `checkInput` method is called when the user clicks a button, so the checking won't be called untill after I fill everything in.